# Karma failing tests because of "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError"

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a web app that throws `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error in various pages. This more like a warning than an error and the web app performs well.

Currently, there isn't such option of fixing the code in order to eliminate this error and I need karma tests to ignore it.

When I run karma test i'm getting:

```
Failed: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.
```

Is there any way to ignore this specific error ?

Comment: Looks like you might be using the same variable over and over for multiple tests.. try initialising this variable before each test by using the `beforeEach` function?

Comment: @Ray I have only one test

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. Usually, even if I get this error in the console running the app, it still doesn't make a Karma/Jasmine test fail (and in this case I wasn't actually getting the console error in the app—only in Karma).

I'm not sure if this was your problem, but mine had to do with how I was using `ngStyle`. Not sure *why* this solved it, but I figured I'd add it here for anyone else looking for answers.

### Error

I was getting the error when I was doing this:

**Template**

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'width.px': (!checked ? widthValue : 0) }">Blah</div>
```

The `widthValue` was being calculated `AfterViewInit`.

I also tried this format too (which also gave me the error):

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'width': (!checked ? widthValue : 0) + 'px' }">Blah</div>
```

### Solution

When I switched the logic to the component and just passed in the resulting style object, it was fine.

**Template**

```
<div [ngStyle]="labelWidth(checked)">Blah</div>
```

**Component**

```
labelWidth(checked: boolean): SafeStyle {
  return {
    width: `${(checked ? this.maxLabelWidth : 0)}px`,
  };
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add opinion here: your solution was probably working afterwards, because you changed the expression from a temporary variable (widthValue), which probably delivers different values each time to a member variable of your class (maxLabelWidth). Your change would only be fair if you used the same expression in both cases. You could do a stackblitz out of it to see it for yourself.